# Using article in a sentence

Tags: articles

I am always confused about using articles. I have three sentences.

1. Depth of friendship doesn't depend on length of acquaintance.
2. A passion for pleasure is the secret of remaining young.
3. Friendship is love with understanding.

1). Which one is right, **depth**, or **the depth**? (length or the length).
2). **Passion** and **secret** have articles but not **pleasure**. Is there any rule for using articles in this sentence?
3) Why doesn't **friendship**  have an article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) and (3) refer to friendship as a concept rather than a particular friendship between two individuals. You could instead say '*The* depth of *a* friendship...'

Similarly, (2) refers to pleasure in general rather than one particular pleasure.